# Implementing a Gantt chart with amcharts and interval axis

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to implement a Gantt chart and I have just found amCharts which looks like what I need. They provide [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/) for Gantt charts. The problem with that example is that they are using dates for the xAxis. I need to show how some processes are executed on a "tick based" timeline so the values for my xAxis would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...

I found that there are different kind of axis types available but the problem with the valueAxis is that I can't draw a column from a value to another so I'm not able to show ranges starting from a different position than 0.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do with amCharts?

This is a graphic example of what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what that red little bar means but your chart looks like a Gantt Chart with the candle stick.

#### Data

Assuming the red bar is your low, then you might have data that looks like the following:

```
let data = [{
    name: "A",
    open: 0,
    close: 3
}, {
    name: "B",
    low: 2,
    open: 3,
    close: 9
}, {
    name: "C",
    low: 4,
    open: 9,
    close: 13
}, {
    name: "D",
    low: 6,
    open: 15,
    close: 20
}, {
    name: "E",
    low: 8,
    open: 13,
    close: 15
}];
```

#### Candle stick Series

Then you can create a Gantt chart with a candle stick series. For a candle stick series to display properly, you have to define `lowValue`, `openValue`, `value` and `highValue` in the data fields of the series:

```
...,
series: [{
    type: "CandlestickSeries",
    dataFields: {
        categoryY: "name",
        lowValueX: "low",
        openValueX: "open",
        valueX: "close",
        highValueX: "close"
    }
}],
...
```

Since the graph you want doesn't have to "tail", you can trick `amchart4` and use `close` value as `highValue`.

[image]

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/kLzh49fv/

If you don't assign the `highValue` field, the range would always start from 0:

```
...,
series: [{
    type: "CandlestickSeries",
    dataFields: {
        categoryY: "name",
        lowValueX: "low",
        openValueX: "open",
        valueX: "close",
        //highValueX: "close"
    }
}],
...
```

[image]

#### Want something fancier?

To emphasis the low value as the red bar, you can add another `StepLineSeries` that uses the `low` values into the chart:

```
...,
series: [{
    type: "CandlestickSeries",
    ...
}, {
    type: "StepLineSeries",
    noRisers: true,
    dataFields: {
        categoryY: "name",
        valueX: "low"
    },
    stroke: "#e62e00",
    strokeWidth: 4,
    startLocation: .3,
    endLocation: .7
}],
...
```

[image]

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/cse496zg/

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is awesome!